# How to fix df.apply using the first rows of a column with if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
def data(x):
    df['chg'] = (df['close'] - df['open']) / df['open'] * 100
    df['chg_high'] = (df['high'] - df['open']) / df['open'] * 100
    df['chg_low'] = (df['low'] - df['open']) / df['open'] * 100
return df

    time                    open    high    low     close   chg         chg_high    chg_low
0   2013-04-01T00:00:00Z    95.50   106.50  93.70   104.70  9.633508    11.518325   -1.884817
1   2013-04-02T00:00:00Z    103.73  116.00  100.10  116.00  11.828786   11.828786   -3.499470
2   2013-04-03T00:00:00Z    116.00  158.41  110.00  133.78  15.327586   36.560345   -5.172414
3   2013-04-04T00:00:00Z    133.87  150.00  119.00  135.00  0.844102    12.049003   -11.107791
4   2013-04-05T00:00:00Z    134.67  144.00  127.09  141.80  5.294423    6.928046    -5.628574
5   2013-04-06T00:00:00Z    141.80  150.03  138.50  141.00  -0.564175   5.803949    -2.327221
```

If the value of x is met for the 'chg_high' column it uses x as profit if not I want it to use the 'chg' column as profit

I wrote that like this:

```
def f(row):
    if row['chg_high'] > x:
        val = 1 + (x/100)
    elif row['chg_high'] < x:
        val = 1 + (df['chg']/100)
    return val
df['profit'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

The problem is that when that value is not met it uses the first rows of the 'chg' column instead of the row I want where the 'chg_high' is lower than x:

```
data(1)

    time                    open    high    low     close   chg         chg_high    chg_low     profit
22  2013-04-23T00:00:00Z    123.73  138.87  121.12  137.29  10.959347   12.236321   -2.109432   1.01    
23  2013-04-24T00:00:00Z    137.30  161.00  134.98  149.00  8.521486    17.261471   -1.689731   1.01    
24  2013-04-25T00:00:00Z    150.00  170.28  123.20  141.90  -5.400000   13.520000   -17.866667  1.01
25  2013-04-26T00:00:00Z    141.90  142.53  126.68  137.30  -3.241720   0.443975    -10.725863  [1.0963350785340316, 1.1182878627205244, 1.153...
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lambda in your apply to have better control over the columns:

```
df['profit'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1+(x/100) if row.chg_high < x else 1+(row.chg/100), axis=1)
```

This would use the same row.
Just take notice that your current conditions don't handle row.chg_high == x